# Merging raster TIFF with different values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, merge, mosaic

I have 2 rasters (TIFF), 16 bit and with 1 band each. The first one showing 2 classes: (1) disturbance (value 1) and (2) no change (value 0). The second raster has 2 classes too: (1) recovery (value 2) and (2)no change(0).

I tried to merge them using *mosaic to new raster* in ArcGIS in order to get a raster with 3 values showing no change, disturbance, and recovery(value 0, value 1, and value 2). Instead of getting those 3 values, I get a raster with 2 values either 0 and 1 or 0 and 2.

Could anyone explain what is the problem and how to tackle it?

[image: 1]

Comment: Do the rasters have the same spatial extent, i.e same number of rows/columns, cell size and they align exactly on top of each other? Do your disturbance pixels overlay your recovery pixels or are they mutually exclusive? You need to add this information to your question.

Comment: Add them together with the raster calculator. The resulting raster will have 4 values: 0)no change, 1)disturbance, 2)recovery, and 3)disturbance+recovery (if they ever overlap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mosaic to New Raster doesn't do what you think it does. It is for joining adjacent rasters with the same range of values into one single larger mosaiced raster.

You want to use the [Raster Calculator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) to do a simple sum of your rasters (i.e. Expression = Raster1 + Raster2). This will give you an output with four potential values - 0 (no change, no change), 1 (disturbance, no change), 2 (recovery, no change), and 3 (disturbance, recovery).

Be sure to check you rasters have their cells aligned and are of the same size before you start. If not, check that the [cell size environment settings](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/cell-size.htm) are appropriate or consider [changing the resolution](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/altering-the-resolution.htm) of one of your rasters to match the other.

Comment: Thank you so much @ycartwhelen. It works. thanks

Comment: Great! If an answer works for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark underneath the answer's up/down voting arrows.